# Failed to load resource: net::ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR - ASP.NET Core - Blazor Webassembly - Nginx Hosting

Tags: asp.net-core, nginx, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I'm hosting a Blazor Webassembly App on a Ubuntu 22.04 Server with Nginx. In the wwwroot folder i'm hosting images (like 1-2MB). When the Website is loading those images i get a Failed to load resource: net::ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR. After clicking more times the Reload Button the Website finally shows me those images. Any idea how to fix this?
here is my prox.config:

```
proxy_redirect          off;
proxy_set_header        Host $host;
proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
client_max_body_size    10m;
client_body_buffer_size 512k;
proxy_connect_timeout   360;
proxy_send_timeout      360;
proxy_read_timeout      360;
proxy_buffers           4 512k;
proxy_buffer_size       256k;
proxy_busy_buffers_size 512k;
```

nginx.conf

```
events {
  worker_connections  4096;  ## Default: 1024
}
http {
    include        /etc/nginx/proxy.conf;
    limit_req_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=one:10m rate=5r/s;
    server_tokens  off;

    sendfile on;
    # Adjust keepalive_timeout to the lowest possible value that makes sense
    # for your use case.
    keepalive_timeout   100;
    client_body_timeout 10; client_header_timeout 10; send_timeout 10;

    upstream example{
        server 127.0.0.1:5000;
    }

    server {
        listen                    443 ssl http2;
        listen                    [::]:443 ssl http2;
        server_name               example.net
        ssl_certificate           /etc/ssl/certs/obcert.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key       /etc/ssl/certs/obcert.key;
        ssl_session_timeout       1d;
        ssl_protocols             TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers off;
        ssl_ciphers               ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384;
        ssl_session_cache         shared:SSL:10m;
        ssl_session_tickets       off;
        ssl_stapling              off;

        add_header X-Frame-Options DENY;
        add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;

        #Redirects all traffic
        location / {
            proxy_pass http://example
            limit_req  zone=one burst=100 nodelay;
        }
    }
}
```

This error happened after i configured the ssl certification for the website.

i tried to configure the proxy.conf and nginx.conf:
proxy_buffer_size
proxy_buffers
proxy_busy_buffers_size
large_client_header_buffers
limit_req  burst